# Drawing the circuit in Qiskit - how to set same style as in Composer?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

A quantum circuit can be visualized in Qiskit with `circuit.draw`. A drawing style can be set with parameter `output` which can have values `mpl`, `text` or `latex` (e.g `circuit.draw(output='mpl')`).

**I am wondering if there is a way to use the same symbols and colors as in IBM Quantum composer since none of the above allow me to do so.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *IBM circuit composer* used to be also known as *IBM Quantum Experience*, or IQX for short. For those historical reasons, the name of the style is `iqx`:

```
from qiskit import *
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.t(1)
circuit.draw('mpl', style='iqx')
```

[image: draw output]

Compare with the composer look:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That’s possible, just do

```
circuit.draw('mpl', style='iqx')
```

Answer (score 3):

For those that are searching for the dark style:

`circuit.draw('mpl', style='iqx-dark')`

[I also refer to the link that explains how one can set the `style` argument.](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.qcstyle.DefaultStyle.html#qiskit.visualization.qcstyle.DefaultStyle)